# ExtJS - grouping and sorting data in huge grid

Tags: asp.net, json, extjs, store

i've a grid where i display some rows based on user filter, about 40.000 rows maximum (this is the worst case, but possible).

I'm working with Extjs + Asp.NET, so JSON store. I know that i can use paging, but i need the grouping (and sorting) funtionality of the grid. Grouping on single page has no sense, i've tried also with infinite scrollbar but the problems persists.

I've seen that grid's rendering, also with 20.000 rows is not so bad, the problem is that in this case the JSONResult passed by Asp.NET to javascript is very huge (about 15 MB and i've reduced at least length of description fields).

So my questions are:
- Can i ZIP in asp.net the json result and decompress in javascript?
- Any other suggestions about managing so many data keeping grid's grouping and sorting funtionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The zip feature is present in HTTP protocol, so it is not to asp.net / javascript to handle this. It depends of IIS (I suppose you use IIS) and browser. 
In your case you need to compress dynamic content, I think that is not enabled by default on IIS :

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730629(v=ws.10).aspx

If you put an apache (or nginx) has revers proxy, it's better to active compression at that level (unload IIS of compression tasks).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this compressing data of json result in asp net and decompression in javascript without change iis configuration?

Comment: I don't think so. And it'll be not so efficient.